# How to get Radio Button option in Devkit Custom Connector?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I am creating a Custom Devkit Connector. I need to add configuration parameters on based of Radio button selection (Same like Reconnection tab of connector).

Could you please tell me how can i create Radio button in Connector Configuration General Tab, and after selecting radio parameter pop up 2-3 configuration fields on based of radio button selection.

Please take a look on attached image (Reconnection Tab). I need to implement same. Thanks a lot in Advance.

Regards, Abhishek Kumar

[Reconnection Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvtPe.jpg)

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Current Devkit does not support radio buttons. Hope future versions have this functionality